# Microphone really REALLY soft after upgrade to 10.15.4

Tags: macos, mojave, upgrade, software-update, microphone

Tested on Google Hangouts, Google Meet, Skype, Facebook Messenger, and Zoom. This is a MacBook Pro 14.3inch.

Even on this screen the microphone only registers when I talk VERY LOUDLY:
[image: Sound within System Preferences]

There were no issues before I upgraded. Since then, there has been another minor upgrade (which I applied). I've also tried with an external headphone that has a mic, and there was no improvement.

EDIT: Installed Windows on an SSD—with Bootcamp drivers—rebooted into it and the mic works. So it's definitely a software problem.

Comment: Try booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (hold `Shift` while booting) to eliminate any 3rd party software causing the  problems. Also issue the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` to see if there is a snapshot of your system prior to the updates that we can roll you back to. Please [edit] your question with the results.

Comment: Do you have the external micro connected when trying to select the volume of the internal micro? disconnect it if it is, since when connected, the internal one should be disconnected by mechanical contacts inside computer. You may have broken connector.

Comment: @Allan `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` returns nothing. I delete things regularly to save disk space. @Yoan I've tried with my external headphones+mic connected & disconnected. If I have broken the connector, can I fix it without breaking warranty? - Would buying an external USB-C sound-card resolve the issue?

Comment: @AT, no and no - since the connector is on the main board. Do you try something like this: https://www.cultofmac.com/681197/blackhole-mac-virtual-audio-driver/ ? it may be normal however - but in this case you may need more software to install.

Comment: Try a reinstall of macOS. This will also replace necessary drivers which might fix the issue.

Comment: @Yoan - As you can see from my screenshot blackhole is installed. - Darn, so new external sound card won't help either =[

Comment: I'm having this trouble. Headset mic (just the one that came with my 1More over-ear cans) works fine on my iPhone, work MacBook Pro (10.14.6), but I have to yell to get it to register anything on personal MacBook Pro (10.15.4). Another headset works fine on the 10.15.4 machine.

Comment: FYI: I also tried with an external mic connected to the mic jack, an external headphone+mic connected via USB-C, a USB-C to headphone jack with my mic & headphone connected, and a bluetooth headphone+mic. Nothing worked.

Comment: Installed Windows on an SSD—with Bootcamp drivers—rebooted into it and the mic works. So it's definitely a software problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. :( My brand new Soundmagic E11C earphones' mic volume is way too soft on my Macbook Pro (15-inch retina touchbar, 2017, MacOS 10.15.7) even when I set the input volume in the System Preferences to maximum. A different headset's mic works fine w/ my Macbook Pro. The Soundmagic earphones' mic works fine with my 2015 iPad Pro.

Answer (score 1):

First, perform a SMC reset by following the instructions for your Mac.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

As commenters have noted, a Safe Boot is also a useful step.  Hold down the Shift key immediately after hearing the startup chimes; you'll notice that login will take longer than normal, and you may see 'Safe Boot' in red letters at the upper right of the login window.  Test the hardware meter again by opening System Preferences > Sound (or press Option and one of the function keys assigned to a Volume control).

Comment: I have reset SMC and PRAM, the problem persists. In Safe Mode, there are no audio devices, input or output.

Comment: In that case, I'd back up your data, reboot into Recovery or Internet Recovery mode, and reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

This started working for me after I updated to 10.15.5.

Comment: I upgraded yesterday… let's test! - EDIT: Nope, still doesn't work :(

Comment: I'm on 10.15.7 and still having the same issue :(